# My folder permissions are not working

Tags: networking, windows-server-2008, permissions, file-permissions

I am configuring a 2008 R2 server for learning experience. The problem I'm having is the following:

Current situation: I created 5 Users, put the users in a global group and made the global group member of a domain local group. I then proceeded to make give the Domain Local Group permissions to enter my ''Administration'' folder.
When the users in the group try to open the folder, it says ''you need permission to perform this action''

What I attempted: Restarting the clients, and servers. I recreated the users and recreated the groups aswell as the folder I am trying to give users access to.
I also attempted giving permission to the folder by just using Global Groups(so without the Domain Local Group part) and that did work. But I need to learn how to do it via AGDLP(so with the domain local group)

Desired situation:
The users in the groups specified above, can access the ''Administration'' folder and create files and folders in it.
There is very little information I could find about this problem on the internet.

I hope to get help here.

Comment: Which server is having the file permissions issue?  What groups? What folders?

Comment: They are just servers I am using for testing and learning. On a drive on the server is a folder called Administration, there are two user accounts in a administration OU and they are both in a Global Group''Administrators''. That global group is member of a Domain Local Group''AdministratorsDL''. When I grant the Domain Local Group ''AdministratorsDL'' access and even full controll to folder ''Administration'' and they still can't access it. Hope thats good explanation. best regards.

Comment: One of they keys to learning anything is to be able to specifically and accurately describe the problem so that you get specific and accurate answers. Saying things like `it does not work` or `they still can't access it` doesn't give us enough useful information from which we can provide answers. So as a start, why not tell us **exactly** what happens and what the **exact** message is when trying to access the folder.

Comment: Thank you, ill try my best. When I use my Windows 7 machine to log onto the domain with one of the administration-worker accounts(which are in the groups i specified in the post above), I get the error ''you need permission to perform this action'' along with a Try Again button. In my server the group clearly has full control on the folder.

Screenshot of the error: http://i.imgur.com/vvUVzte.png

Screenshot of the security tab of the folder: http://i.imgur.com/BOBtpSm.png

Comment: Completely reworded the post. can a mod approve it agian?

Comment: I can't tell if that's a user or a group that you gave permissions to for that folder; can you clarify? Have you tested it by giving the user account direct permissions to the folder to compare the results?  How are you trying to access the file (mounted drive, unc, etc...)?

Comment: What are your "Share" permissions?